# Abort due to constraint violation in SQL Java

Tags: java, sql, database

I have created a database with the name of Sequence in Java.

```
stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sequence(Seq_Num TEXT Primary Key not null, Seq_ID TEXT, "
       + E_ID TEXT," + "FOREIGN KEY(E_ID) REFERENCES Emitter(E_ID))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Now clearly I have not labeled the column Seq_ID as UNIQUE.

So when I execute the following statement:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Sequence(Seq_Num, Seq_ID, E_ID) VALUES('" + value + "','" + model.txtSaveAs.getText() 
         + "','" + model.namesList.get(i) + "')";
stmt.execute(sql);
```

It is giving me this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (column Seq_ID is not unique)
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS? Is that table already existing with seq_id as unique?

Comment: No i have never defined it as unique from the start

Comment: `Seq_Num` is `PRIMARY KEY` which is `UNIQUE` (and `NOT NULL`) by definition...

Comment: The problem was with Seq_ID

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the table initially contained 4 columns but i had edited the create table statement. But as the table already existed so the changes were never implemented in the table. So I first deleted the table by the statement:

```
DROP TABLE Sequence
```

And then created the table again; this time with 3 columns.

Comment: That is what I said initially :) Either with sequence_id or not, 2nd column was being taken as sequence